# Scala Pattern Matching on Option

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, option-type

I read [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 5: The Option Type](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html) and he suggested that a way to match on options. I implemented his suggestion here:

```
s3Bucket match {
  case Some(bucket) =>
    bucket.putObject(partOfKey + key + file.getName, file)
    true
  case None =>
    false
}
```

But I have some questions on how it actually works. Namely, since `s3Bucket` is of type `Option[Bucket]`, how does `case Some(bucket)` unwrap `s3Bucket` into `bucket`? What exactly is going on under the hood?

Comment: you should also read about extractors in his series of articles. It's article number one http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html

Comment: @maks thanks! I read a Scala textbook to learn Scala so I didn't actually go through the articles, I just look at them as a reference. I'll read them through now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is: extractors.

What's an extractor? I won't go into details here, but - in short- an extractor is a method capable of destructuring an instance of a type, extracting a value from it.

In scala any `A` that provides an `unapply` method with this signature

```
def unapply(object: A): Option[B]
```

can be used in pattern matching, where it will extract a value of type `B` if the matches succeeds.

There's plenty of resources online you can read about this mechanism. A good one is this [blog post](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) by Daniel Westheide.

Back to your question, `Some` and `None` both provide an `unapply` method by the virtue of being case classes (which automatically extend `Product`), so they can be used in pattern matching.

A sketchy implementation would go pretty much like:

```
object Some {
  def unapply[A](a: Some[A]) = Some(a.get)
}

object None {
  def unapply(object: None) = None
}
```